# Pull elements randomly from an array 3 by 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays, random

I have an array with list items :

```
var listArray = [];

$("ul li").each(function(){
    listArray.push($(this));
});

var item = listArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*listArray.length)];

item.css({
    "transform":"scale(1)"
});
```

and i shuffled the array as it mentioned in answers but still i am not able to pull the elements from it one by one in intervals

if you have a better idea how to do it please tell me.

**DEMO** : https://jsfiddle.net/rnfrxL1b/3/

Comment: There are no stupid questions, only stupid answers. Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: Taking 4 random elements is simply taking one random element four times.

Comment: @Nit not if you don't want to take one specific element more than once.

Comment: @GuiImamura Regardless of which he wants, there is a standard way to do this which one can easily search for.

Answer (score 2):

You may first shuffle the array and then pull values from the shuffled array either one by one or 4 by 4. See shuffle method: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Comment: ok i shuffled array but the problem is that i dont know how to pull elements from it 4 by 4 in intervals i have tried it with loops but without success

Comment: @FrankeyWakey Did you try array slice?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want: [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2450954/3471286)

Accepted/most upvoted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/3471286):

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
```

Which is the Fisher-Yates (aka Knuth) Shuffle, according to the author of the answer. Please see original answer and links in it for more details.

Comment: Yeah, I was too slow :(

Comment: It's the thought that counts :)

Comment: i used this shuffle algorythm but i still have problem to get the elements from an aray 4 by 4 in interval

Comment: @FrankeyWakey please clarify that for me. So you'll have (4 * n) elements in the array, and what to get 4 random elements per iteration?